# Docker Community Edition for production environment?

Tags: docker, zfs, btrfs, zfsonlinux

I was planning to use docker in a production environment. Now I see Docker Inc. differentiates strongly free and paid versions with the Community and Enterprise Editions. This sentence about CE is kind of scaring me:

> Get started with Docker and experimenting with container-based apps.

I don't want to experiment in a production environment. I would like to use the EE but at this moment I cannot afford even the Enterprise Edition Basic, so I have to stay with the CE.

What implications does this have in terms of stability and security? How big is the risk I'm taking If use the CE and how can mitigate this risk? How important are the features of the EE (Docker Certified, Image Management,etc.)([Docker Pricing Plans](https://www.docker.com/pricing))?

I also would like to use the zfs or the btrfs storage driver. I don't see any btrfs storage driver support for any of the linux distributions here:
 [storage drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/#docker-ee-and-cs-engine). For the zfs storage driver there is support only for Ubuntu. On the other hand I have seen that from the free linux distributions Ubuntu is not so popular as Debian and CentOS for server use. Can I still use CentOS with btrfs or zfs storage driver? What are the 
implications if I go with CentOS or if I go with Ubuntu? What are the things I have to take into consideration for one or the other choice?

Comment: I use Docker-CE in a Prod environment. Docker by nature is going to have various levels of stability. Since they are on a three-month release cycle currently, you could just hold off several versions. If you're able to get stable running containers at a certain engine version, just stick to that until you need to do security upgrades. Validate in your non-prod environment.  As long as you abide by the Security best practices (e.g. non-privileged containers, non-TCP local socket) you should be fine.